# Is there a desktop (AIR) app for adobe Buzzword?

Tags: adobe, air, desktop

Awhile ago i read about adobe coming out with an AIR app for Buzzword. I searched google and the most recent updates I can find about it are all the way back in 2008, which is REALLY strange, and I can't find a download ANYWHERE.

Does anyone know what happened? Is there an AIR app for Buzzword? Or... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah, Adobe became careless with the whole Acrobat and Buzzword issue. Lack of resources, company vision, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

This will be so good to be truth :)
Here is a discussion on this http://forums.adobe.com/thread/94505?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Existing Buzzword application already checks if the Flash runtime is a Web based or desktop based. So it does support but the offical .air is yet to come.